# How to query a property of an object that is an array in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6

I have a result set of objects that look like this

```
{
  category: "Chicken",
  description: "Lorem ipsum dolor",
  deliveryPortal: [0 => "City Pantry", 1 => "Feedr"]
} 

{
  category: "Beef",
  description: "Lorem ipsum dolor",
  deliveryPortal: [0 => "City Pantry"]
} 

{
  category: "Beef",
  description: "Lorem ipsum dolor",
  deliveryPortal: [0 => "Feedr"]
}
```

I need to do a filter on the list of object like `filter item where deliveryPortal == 'given value'` where `'given value'` is any of the deliveryPortal values. Problem is, the filter works fine when the `deliverPortal` property has just one element but when it has more than one like the first object, it doesn't work. How can i filter on the `deliveryPortal` when it contains multiple elements?

Comment: None of that is JavaScript. Please show your **actual** code.

Comment: That is not valid object syntax though, if you put that into the console, you'll get a `malformed arrow function parameter list` error

Comment: Bit of mixup with PHP it seems.

Comment: @p.s.w.g that is javascript and that is a dynamic result i am writing to my browser's console.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `.includes` on the inner arrays:

```
 array.filter(it => it.deliveryPortal.includes("City Pantry"))
```